# Manually added legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am stucked with this.

```
los<-data.frame(los=rnorm(400))
los<-los|>mutate(simlos=rnbinom(400,size = 3.15559,mu=150.63))
ggplot(los,aes(x=los))+geom_density(color="blue",aes(color="real data"))+
  geom_density(aes(x=simlos,color="simulated data"),color="red")+
  labs(title = "Densities Length of Stay")+
  scale_color_manual(name='Densities LOS',
                     breaks=c('real data', 'simulated data'),
                     values=c('real data'='blue', 'simulated data'='red'))
```

I have following the instructions that I found about how to add manual legends but it does not work. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `color` outside of the aesthetics. If you want to manually create, you need to have them in the `aes` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(los,aes(x=los))+
  geom_density(aes(color="real data"))+
  geom_density(aes(x=simlos,color="simulated data"))+
  labs(title = "Densities Length of Stay")+
  scale_color_manual(name='Densities LOS',
                     breaks=c('real data', 'simulated data'),
                     values=c('real data'='blue', 'simulated data'='red'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>